# Set Value on PHP Object Dynamic Properties

Tags: php, oop

I have a php object, for example: album. Album has proporties img1, img2, img3

Now i use iteration(loop) for setting it, for example:

```
for($i=1;$i<3;$i++){
   $album->img{$i}="image".$i.".jpg";
}
```

However, the value cannot be set, so i wondering is there more appropriate approach to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for($i=1;$i<3;$i++){
   $album->{"img".$i}="image".$i.".jpg";
}
```

Comment: i agree with this answer.