# How can I set value to file in php?

Tags: php, html

> To set PHP variable value to file

```
$old_image_path = $row['image'];
```

> I want to set $old_image_path to file but it dose not work

```
  <label for="image" class="pull-right">Student Pic</label>
  <input type="file" value="<?=$old_image_path?>" name="image" id="image" required="required">
</div>
```

Comment: please read about files in html forms! This is not how it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set Value on PHP Object Dynamic Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33656673/set-value-on-php-object-dynamic-properties)

Comment: i want to update student information when i want to change all old information must fill their places. is it possible to fill file from mysql database

Comment: set value in the sense you want to display that old_image_path in your input field?

Comment: yes i want to set that old_image_path in input field

Comment: Are you getting value in $old_image_path ?

Answer (score 1):

Please put the image source path under the src parameter of the img tag if you want to display the old image. The input type "File" is to select a file e. g. for uploading the file to a destination.

```
<img src="<?php echo $old_image_path; ?>" name="image" id="image" required />
```